# Execute npm install after bundle install by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, npm-install

In a ruby on rails project,

Will it be possible to execute **npm install** after executing **bundle install** without the developer executing it? The developer won't need any npm package from package.json in his every day work, but we are using Husky as a pre-commit hook to run rubocop before committing his code.

Comment: This sounds like what makefile does. In ROR, you can use a rake task to install all dependcies

Comment: I think you could try creating your own bundler plugin that will do the job (bundler provides some hooks for the process and API to plug into)